# django tastypie dehydrate from reverse relation

Tags: django, tastypie

Suppose i have :

models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def get_album(self):
        return self.album_set.all()

class Album(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'blahblah')
```

api.py:

```
class PersonResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Person.objects.all()

class AlbumResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Album.objects.all()
```

How can i dehydrate a field on `PersonResource` so its value is `.get_album()` ?

I Tried to Use ToManyField like this :

```
albums = fields.ToManyField(readonly = True)
```

But it throws :

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
Exception Location: C:\PHOTOBLOG\photoblog\person\api.py in PersonResource, line 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question, what we need is to add this on `PersonResource` :

```
albums = fields.ToManyField('myapp.api.AlbumResource', 'album_set', full = True)
```

no need to define custom method or dehydrate.